# Is there an alternative to exec in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm making an integrator program with the simpson 1/3 method  and I want the user to give me a function and interval of integration, and then return the result. I figure that I can use exec to make dynamic code, so I use it to create the function. This is my code:

```
from math import *

class CreaFormula:
    def __init__(self,formula):
        self.fun = "def f(x):\n  return %s" % formula


class Integrador:
    def __init__(self,f):
        #integration interval 
        a = 0
        b = 1
        n = 600 
        h = (b-a)/n
        #method
        self.s = f(a) + f(b)
        for i in range(1,n):
            if i%2 == 0:
                self.s = self.s + 2*f(a+i*h)
            else:
                self.s = self.s + 4*f(a+i*h)

        self.s = self.s*(h/3)
        vr = -cos(1) + e
        self.er = abs((vr -self.s) /vr)


formula = input()
MiFo = CreaFormula(formula)
f1 = MiFo.fun
exec(f1)
MyInt = Integrador(f)

a = MyInt.s
b = MyInt.er
print(a)
```

So basically I want to put everything that is at the end of the code inside a class, so I can call it later by another code, but if I do that it shows an error that f is not defined, because it is created with exec. So is there a way to not use exec but still create a function from user's input?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of the string. Why don't you just bind an actual function to the attribute?

Comment: The problem with `exec` is that it allows a user to create a function that can do anything your program can do. If that's what you're *trying* to accomplish, then that's the right tool tool to use. That said, you should understand the security implications of this: what users are allowed to use this program? Is it OK that they can run any code they want on this machine?

Comment: You might also want to look at sympy

Comment: I would try ```ast.parse('formula')``` and then try to process the tree as an expression. I would avoid using eval or exec unless it's 'just to test' code for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

If the question is just how to construct a function object that can evaluate a user-supplied expression, you'll probably have an easier time using `eval` than `exec`:

```
def create_function_from_formula(formula):
    def user_function(x):
        return eval(formula, globals(), {'x': x})
    return user_function
```

Of course, even with `eval`, if someone provides a malicious `formula`, it can do *anything*, up to and including executing any other program included on the computer. So only do this if you trust the person providing the `formula` to essentially take over your computer. In particular, you should *never* do this if `formula` can come from a user who is not physically logged in to your computer already.